# Ускорение время в ros в несколько раз

Tags: ros

Как ускорить время в ros во много раз, используя rostime API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для ускорения/замедления времени в ROS следует покапаться с API *Time*,в частности с `Clock` и `Time`. 
Перед запуском вашего симулятора:

`rosparam set use_sim_time true`

После чего запускаем скрипт, который паблишит новые значения времени в топик `/clock`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime
import rospy
import time

from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Clock
from std_msgs.msg import Time, Duration


rospy.init_node('sim_clock', anonymous=True)
clock_pub = rospy.Publisher("/clock", Clock, queue_size=10)
clock = Clock()
clock.clock = rospy.Time.from_sec(100)
r = 40

# Значение для duration менял от 0.01(очень медленно) и до 0.3(очень быстро)
# Можете сами поиграться со значениями, которые будут зависеть от ваших нужд и железа  рабочей машины
duration = rospy.Duration.from_sec(0.3)
sleep_rate = r

sleep_duration = 1./sleep_rate

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    t1 = time.time()
    clock.clock = clock.clock + duration
    clock_pub.publish(clock)
    time.sleep(max(0, sleep_duration - (time.time() - t1)))
```

После чего запускаете ваш симулятор и продолжаете работу. Важно соблюдать алгоритм запуска и будет счастье.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно, клиенты в ROS используют системные часы компьютера (т.н. "настенные часы"). Для ускорения, замедления и пр. времени, нужно задействовать /clock для симулирования времени. Для этого, нужено установить `/use_sim_time` параметр до инициализации.

Clock Message:

- roslib/Clock (до C Turtle)
- [rosgraph_msgs/Clock (Diamondback и после)](http://docs.ros.org/api/rosgraph_msgs/html/msg/Clock.html): `time clock`

В любом случае, почитайте про ROS Clock, например на [Clock](http://wiki.ros.org/Clock).

Comment: на сколько я понял, следует сделать ноду, которая будет паблишить значение в топик /clock?